# How to get the Model.Value in my View. using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

can I do something like this to get the Mode.check value in my view..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check = <%(Model.Check); %>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      if(check == "Save")
      {
        $("#ObnRemove").show();
         $("#ObnAdd").val('Save');
      }
      else
      {
          $("#ObnRemove").hide();
      }
        $("#TextEdit").click(function () {
            $("#ObnRemove").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

but i am not getting Model.check value?

what I am doign wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var check = '<%=Model.Check%>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `<%: Model.Check %>`

Comment: caveat - the ":" is only mvc2?

Comment: Actually, I believe ":" is only mvc2 under .NET 4.0.  We orignally had MVC2 under 3.5 and the notation was not supported.